# cURL command returns invalid request when copied from Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: curl, google-chrome-devtools

When using Chrome Developer Tools to copy the cURL command to clipboard and running the command in iTerm, the response is

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><return_code><![CDATA[1]]></return_code><error_message><![CDATA[Invalid request.]]></error_message></root>`

Here is the cURL command:

`curl 'https://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v=QcIy9NiNbmo' -H 'Origin: https://www.youtube.com' -H 'X-YouTube-Page-Label: youtube_20160714_RC2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36' -H 'X-YouTube-Variants-Checksum: 634d96c10153993c2fa1ff127bb5f5fa' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'X-YouTube-Page-CL: 127470335' -H 'Referer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcIy9NiNbmo' -H 'X-YouTube-Client-Version: 1.20160714' -H 'X-Youtube-Identity-Token: QUFFLUhqblJscnRybVd5NUdiMk5YcTdoUUE5el9oajNNUXw=' --data 'session_token=QUFFLUhqa2xneXkxMWN1VWRZTndWc1FTbXFpeDhKZjRFd3xBQ3Jtc0tueEQ0dEp3ZThFeFNQT0FnZldKbWp1UmZ0bmxZeGxwS0MxRFBTTVhlaV9Pek5QNFQ3TkV1TTBFck5WR1RJTGpPd3JtdS1TMnBjbTNjYmV0MThNbHdMQmxyZnQzLTRkcWl1dWU4M3lkbWEyQlgzdEUxRmJtNnB2bl9uOFVzSWN6Nm5sXzFRenNIWnc2dXJkMFFZNVZhdktNc3JoRmc%3D' --compressed`

Why is this request invalid?

Answer (score 1):

The request requires an active session ("session_token" header). Most likely the session referenced in the curl requests is not valid any more. This could be a timing issue or the server invalidating it because detecting the change of user-agent.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is it possible to prevent the session from becoming inactive? Or to generate a new active session for the curl request?

Comment: The info stored in the session (the "session_token" data) is specific to the youtube application. This info can referrence the http enviroment at the moment of the requests ( cookies, localtime, headers,addresses,... ). It's encrypted, so you cannot really peek to into it. 

You could issue curl calls, keeping the state among them (using cookies with same storage) performing all the requests (login, query,....). This is  non-trivial and prone to break at any change.

Have you considered the API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) ? I guess it is easier, documented and robust.